# Bootstrap is not working in Built angular project?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm working on an angular project, and I'm using bootstrap CSS and js for styling. Once I built that project the bootstrap is not working properly. If I use the CDN link in the project then the bootstrap styling working inbuilt project. How shall I overcome the problem?? I can't use the CDN link for this project, Is there any alternative solution for this??

Comment: What do you mean by styling? Are you referring just to css or js part? Show how you've added boostrap

Comment: @David Using the command "npm install --save bootstrap", and then added in angular.json files, css and scripts list. While in development the properties of bootstrap working correctly. Once I built and serve with nginx server some bootstrap properties not working...

Comment: Any error in the console? If not, what kind of error/incorrect behaviour do you have? What do you call properties of bootstrap?

Comment: @David Incorrect behaviour, The properties I mentioned is the classes used in bootstrap for html tags

Answer (score 1):

You can install Bootstrap module

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

and include bootstrap css file in your style css

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Comment: you can add js in your angular.json in script tag, like "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"

Comment: make sure jquery module is also installed

Comment: Both modules are present in the scripts tag, still the built using the command "npm run build:prod" module is not working while served in nginx..

Answer (score 0):

I am using bootstrap for my website and did not have any issues. Did you use Angular CLI to add bootstrap to your project? I used the Angular CLI for mine and used the following code to add it to my project:

ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

My angular.json looks like that: 
[image]
I hope it helps!

Comment: installed using npm command.., the angular.json shows the same but in the built project bootstrap properties not working accordingly???

Answer (score 0):

if you want pure bootstrap, as [Shilpa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7043923/shilpa-lalwani) mentioned install pure bootstrap. This will install a latest variation of bootstrap 4

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

Now go to your `angular.json` file and add what [Ashvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13422552/ashvin-pal) mentioned

```
....
....
"styles": [

          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
....
....
```

**Example** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dykx6n

Comment: As you mentioned this method tested, but no use. One more point is to make is that the built project is served using nginx server, is there any effect on that???

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you server-side rendering i.e. using angular-universal ?

Comment: well, I don't know what you meant by angular-univeral, once the project completed then built that project using command "npm run build:prod", the built module is served using the nginx server that's it. Is that a server side rendering??

Comment: K you seem to be doing, normal angular. So things should work normally. Verify if the `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` exists. If still having issues, try to create a minimal reproducible example, probably in stack-blitz